# Generating classes from XML in C++ (but NOT using CodeSynthesisXSD)

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

We require the ability to generate C++ classes from XML (akin to JAXB in Java) but for commercial reasons **do not** wish to use CodeSynthesisXSD. Are there any other libraries out there that will allow this? The platform we are targeting is Windows.

We have been looking at [xmlbeansxx](https://github.com/TouK/xmlbeansxx) but this has not been maintained for 5 years and requires an older version of Boost than we have currently in our system (and do not want to have multiple Boost versions).

Answer (score 0):

CodeSynthesis XSD author here.

First of all, a small nitpick: CodeSynthesis XSD doesn't generate C++ classes from XML. It generates them from XML Schema. From your question it appears that XSD would have worked for you. So I assume you are actually looking to generate C++ from XML Schema.

Now to your question. I don't believe there is a usable and more liberally-licensed C++ tool out there that can do this. Also, if your XML vocabulary is fairly small (e.g., a configuration format), then you may consider using XSD under the free proprietary license. It allows you to use XSD in a commercial application without having to release your source code as long as the amount of the generated code is less than 10,000 lines. And, as the name suggests, it is free (as in no charge).